# How to call fragment from an activity in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on `android fragments`. I am getting an issue with `activity` and `fragment` in my app. i.e I created a `button` in `fragment1` and called an `activity1` in that `button` click. Again in `activity1` I created another `button` and called `activity2`.
Now from `activity2`, I called `activity1` and from `activity1` I am trying to call `fragment1`. But it is showing an error at id(can anyone tell me which id we need to give). I researched google on how to call `fragment` from `activity` but I didn't find any solution for this. Please help me out with this issue.  Thanks in advance.

My code:

Activity1.class

```
public void back(View v) {
MyFragment1 fragmentS1 = new MyFragment1();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.frame_container, fragmentS1).commit();
}
```

Logcat Error:

```
04-10 10:55:28.876: E/AndroidRuntime(22103): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 10:55:28.876: E/AndroidRuntime(22103): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a0004 (com.vizteck.navigationdrawer:id/frame_container) for fragment Fragment1{429cba90 #0 id=0x7f0a0004}
04-10 10:55:28.876: E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:895)
04-10 10:55:28.876: E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
04-10 10:55:28.876: E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-10 10:55:28.876: E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
04-10 10:55:28.876: E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
04-10 10:55:28.876: E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-10 10:55:28.876: E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-10 10:55:28.876: E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 10:55:28.876: E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
04-10 10:55:28.876: E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 10:55:28.876: E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 10:55:28.876: E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
04-10 10:55:28.876: E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
04-10 10:55:28.876: E/AndroidRuntime(22103):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: for **loose coupling** you should use interface concept.

Comment: You have mentioned you are getting error. But where is your logcat error ? @Amrutha

Answer (score 8):

Try this..

Remove android from this `android.R.id.frame_container`

if you are using `activity1` **extends** `Activity` use `getFragmentManager()` or if you are using `activity1` **extends** `FragmentActivity` use `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

like below

```
MyFragment1 fragmentS1 = new MyFragment1();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragmentS1).commit();
```

Comment: `getFragmentManager()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

```
Fragment frag;
FragmentManager fm1 = MainActivity.this
    .getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm1.beginTransaction();
frag = new Animal_Activity();
ft1.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, frag);
ft1.commit();
```

Answer (score 4):

**Write it in your activity like below**

```
Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.output1, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can call like this:

```
Fragment fragment = new FragmentName(); 
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_main, fragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do This:-

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            MyFragment1 fragmentS1 = new MyFragment1();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, mBarcodeScreen);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Good Luck !!